# Saving to multiple databases in Django admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to know if there is a way to save data into multiple databases (storages) through the Django admin panel.

What I want to do is - when a user is saving smth in the admin panel - all the data will be saved into two storages (both specified in host_settings)

Comment: I meant - saving something, e.g. some piece of data.
I actually found an answer and I'll be posting it in a few moments

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.

Turned out you can specify the storage in the *save()* method with an optional parameter - *using*

An example would be: `Something.save(using = 'name_of_the_database')`